# http request can't be performed by culrpp lib and others same problems

Tags: c++

I want do http request for simple http page and i am add (curlpp, utilspp, curl) to include folder of project but IDE when debug found errors such as:
-i set runtime library: Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)-

```
My code
#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
// RAII cleanup

curlpp::Cleanup myCleanup;

// Send request and get a result.
// Here I use a shortcut to get it in a string stream ...

int main()
{
std::ostringstream os;
os << curlpp::options::Url(std::string("https://example.com/"));

string asAskedInQuestion = os.str();
return 0;
}
```

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_setopt referenced in function "public: void __thiscall curlpp::internal::CurlHandle::option(enum CURLoption,void *)" (??$option@PAX@CurlHandle@internal@curlpp@@QAEXW4CURLoption@@PAX@Z)    Project2    D:\Pro\Project2\Project2\Source.obj 1

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream > &,class curlpp::OptionTrait,class std::allocator >,10002> const &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABV?$OptionTrait@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@$0CHBC@@curlpp@@@Z) referenced in function _main  Project2    D:\Pro\Project2\Project2\Source.obj

Comment: Are you sure that there is operator<< overload which takes return value of curlpp::options::Url(std::string("https://example.com/")) ?

Comment: Looks like you are not linking to the .lib file of CURL or your library path is incorrect. CURL documentation should provide necessary info.

Comment: i test with another url just contain text and i do all this 
Properties -> VC++ -> Add Directory thirdparty/include (the path)

Properties -> VC++ -> Add Library thirdparty/lib/static-debug (the path)

Properties -> C++ -> Preprocessor -> Add CURL_STATICLIB

Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories Library -> thirdparty/lib/static-debug (the path) Linker -> Input add: C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\build-libcurl-windows\third-party\libcurl\lib\static-debug\libcurl_a_debug.lib (the full path of the lib file)